# Openssl certificate for Azure website

Tags: azure, ssl, openssl

I am getting an error, when I try to add binding to ssl certificate.

Error:

```
Failed to add SSL binding. The certificate with thumbprint '877EC1DA24CD9D4713FD4107A83AC0EE5A4654E4' is invalid for SSL. The Enhanced Key Usage must be present and must contain Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1).
```

Below is the method to generate ssl.

Step 1

```
Create file domain.rs.txt
```

Step 2

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=DK
ST=Jutland
L=Haderslev
O=Justlearn ApS
OU=Haderslev
emailAddress=team@justlearn.com
CN = www.justlearn.rs

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = justlearn.rs
DNS.2 = www.justlearn.rs
```

Step 3

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out domain.rs.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout domain.rs.key -config domain.rs.txt
```

Step 4

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in domain.rs.csr -signkey domain.rs.key -out domain.rs.crt
```

Step 5

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in domain.rs.crt -inkey domain.rs.key -out mycert.pfx
```

Comment: Looks like this is answered in https://serverfault.com/a/573038/236787.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Certificate with XCA. then in the key usage tab make sure you select the "TLS Web Server Authentication" options. also check is critical.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfpyy.png)

After that you need to export your certificate and key.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD7HB.png)
Then Use OpenSsl to convert the .crt to PFX is case you needed. see command bellow.

```
pkcs12 -export -out C:\Certificate\BBBakingdecor.pfx -inkey 
C:\Certificate\bakingdecor.pem -in C:\Certificate\bakingdecor.crt
```